# Macro to Convert Column cells "Number saved as Text" to Number Format

Tags: excel, vba

I tried the following but it's not working:

```
Sub Enter_Values3()
Dim dbl As Double
dbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Columns("A:A").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Please give a sample of the data you are trying to convert...

Comment: I once tried that... Didn't find a solution to that.
Just to mention: if you select all the cells, you can do it in two clicks.

Comment: Try `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "0"`. You don't need the `dbl` reference...

Comment: Alternative solution I just found, don't know if it works: [Converting Numbers stored as text to Numbers](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=64027)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Marty McVry [Link worked](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=64027)

```
Sub macro()
Range("A:A").Select 'specify the range which suits your purpose
Sheets(2).Select
With Selection
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
    .Value = .Value
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using NumberFormat or CSNG?

Comment: Yes to `NumberFormat` but I no to`CSNG` (will Gooogle to see what this is).  Thanks for the comment